# how to link together masterTableView with detailView in Swift

Tags: swift, url, detailview

I'm able to display my links through an array of urls on masterTableView , but I'm not able to link it with detailView .

Is there any way to do this , I have a lot of confusion in it .

Answer (score 0):

Just control drag from your cell in the `tableView` to your `detailView`

Comment: I'm not able to control drag

Comment: can you add a printscreen? You probably have something funny going on

Comment: I'm new to developing so no idea how to link , just finding a perfect way to do

Comment: I haven't figured the way do do this yet